# Java: remove a range of indices from a list

Tags: java

Consider a linked list of strings I got from somewhere

```
LinkedList<String> names = getNames();
```

Now, I want to remove the first **k** elements from the list. Currently, I'll do it this way:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < k ; i++) {
    names.removeFirst();
}
```

Is there some way to do it more efficiently and to instead call something like:

```
names.removeRange(0, k);
```

Note that I prefer not to construct a whole new list using `sublist()`, as for small `k` values, popping `k` times would be even more efficient than constructing the new list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe Something like this :

```
names.subList(0, k).clear();
```

this is more efficient but doesn't release memory according to [sublist](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) it's just a view:

```
names.sublist(k, names.size());
```

Comment: Won't it be more efficient to simply do `names = names.sublist(k, names.size())` ?

Comment: I prefer not to construct a new list, as for small `k` values, it would be less efficient that simply popping `k` times

Comment: @SomethingSomething `subList` doesn't create a new list. It's a view over the same underlying list.